# Ninject nested constructor argument

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

the way im binding my services with nested constructors is working but it seems like there's a better way to inject these nested constructors.
Please tell me what is the proper way to do it for this kind of scenario, also if there is something wrong with the way I layer my application kindly point it out also thank you!

Please check the codes below:

AuthorController.cs

```
public class AuthorsController : Controller
{
    IAuthorService authorService;
    public AuthorsController(IAuthorService _authorService)
    {
        authorService = _authorService;
    }
}
```

AuthorService.cs

```
public class AuthorService :IAuthorService
{
    IAuthorRepository repo = null;

    public AuthorService(IAuthorRepository _authorRepository)
    {
        repo = _authorRepository;
    }
}
```

AuthorRepository

```
public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
{
    MyContext Context = null;
    public AuthorRepository(MyContext _context)
    {
        Context = _context;
    }
}
```

NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        MyContext db = new MyContext();

        //this is where i have my doubts
        kernel.Bind<IAuthorService>().ToConstructor(x =>
            new AuthorService(new AuthorRepository(db))
        );
    }
```

**EDIT:** after several tries I found another way to achieve my goal which i think is much cleaner(note: I dont know how it automatically find the MyContext parameter of AuthorRepository but it does)

2nd Way:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IAuthorService>().To<AuthorService>();
    kernel.Bind<IAuthorRepository>().To<AuthorRepository>();
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `Step 5` in https://medium.com/@chrisverwijs/a-step-by-step-guide-to-using-ninject-for-dependency-injection-in-c-68a125bd7fa4

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya ok ty

Comment: @Chetan it says "Ninject will automatically figure out which concrete implementations to pass into constructors based on the Bindings", does it mean all i have to do is Bind<IAuthorService>().To<AuthorService>() and including IAuthorRepository would be injected?

Comment: Yes... if you just bind the individual services using the approach suggested in the link, it should resolve the dependencies on its own. Did you try binding that way?